# Empty req.body using express router

Tags: node.js, express

**Why *params* might be empty when doing this?**

> curl -X POST http://localhost:9002/foobar -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "year":2021}'

**app.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

// Add a router for each namespace
const myRoutes = require('./routes/foo');
app.use(myRoutes);

// Defaults
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('GET /');
    res.send('');
});
app.post('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('POST /');
    res.send('');
});

app.listen(9002);
```

**routes/foo.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const https = require('https');

router.post('/foobar', async (req, res) => {
    res.send(await foobar(req.body));
});
async function foobar(params) {
    console.log('/foobar...');  
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    year = currentYear;
    console.log(params); //<------------------------------ This is empty
    if(params.year){
        year=params.year;//<---This is never run
    }
    console.log('year is '+year); //shown on console, the code is being run
    //...
}

module.exports = router;
```

**console**

```
/foobar...
{}
year is 2021
```

Sad part of the story: it works on systemA (localhost) but doesn't on systemB (work).
I might be doing something wrong, but so far I haven't been able to figure what is it.

Comment: you didn't  specify the port in curl request, add snippets of your console too

Comment: did you solve the issue? are you receiving the body in `app.post("*", fn())`

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar no, the issue is not solved, neither im getting req.body on app.post

Comment: Pleas check the curl once, body needs to be sent as --data-raw 
you can see the references here https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html